# android NDK cannot locate symbol "mmap64"

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, video-processing, ndk-build, android-ffmpeg

I'm a beginer in ffmpep, I did my first simple project as this tutorial

> https://proandroiddev.com/android-ndk-how-to-integrate-pre-built-libraries-in-case-of-the-ffmpeg-7ff24551a0f?gi=72f471c40747

But it raised the error "cannot locate mmap64 symbol...".

Help me please!

This is my logcat:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libavutil.so" needed by "libnative-lib.so"; caused by cannot locate symbol "mmap64" referenced by "libavutil.so"...
>                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
>                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
>                                                          at video.media.tainguyen.test_ffmpeg_ndk.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:12)
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I built my so file with NDK r17, ffmpeg version 3.4, ubuntu 12.04.5(64bit) (I just built it in ubuntu, my current OS is windows 7 64 bit)
My project is created in android studio 2.2 using NDK r17

> compileSdkVersion 27
>
> buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
>
> minSdkVersion 15
>
> targetSdkVersion 27
>
> externalNativeBuild {
>               cmake {
>                   cppFlags ""
>                   arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
>                   targets "native-lib","avutil","avformat","avcodec"
>               }
>           }
>           ndk {
>               abiFilters "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi"
>           }

Comment: Hey, did you solve your problem?
I faced same problem that a little bit different. I get error that is caused by cannot locate symbol "atof" referenced by "libavformat-58.so"... 
But when I compile the example that the site contains. I am not getting an error.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I am having the exact same problem with Android 4.4.

Comment: did you find a solution?